# Keeping comma separated values in one column

Tags: excel, csv

I have a .CSV file that has for example an entry like this:

```
grop_name,policy_name,"path" : "permission1", "permission2", "permission3"
```

everything works great until the permissions, excel takes that and creates a column for each permission. Is there a way I can format it so that excel puts `"path" : "permission1", "permission2", "permission3"` into one column?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the problem is the quotes. `"path : permission1, permission2, permission3"` should be parsed correctly

Comment: Thanks, yea, need to strip the quotes out of there, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If in excel you want to read inside a cell

```
"path" : "permission1", "permission2", "permission3"
```

the right formatting is

```
"""path"" : ""permission1"", ""permission2"", ""permission3"""
```

Because (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another
> double quote